# react-native how to catch warning in release

Tags: react-native

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        encryptInfo: '',
        testKey:this.props.test.key,
    };
}
```

if this.props.test.key is undefined

in debug mode，it will show [warn] in xcode terminal and show YellowBox，

but if in release I can't get any info

and I try to rewrite `console.warn`  it also no use in release.

Is any way catch warning in release ?

Comment: Why would you want to show such information to the end user?

Comment: I want to catch warning and send these information to my server, some warning will become a bug, if the above code write in a view,  this view will not be entry. I want fix this bug in time, rather than waiting for the user to notify us.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is Crashlytics which comes with Fabric (https://fabric.io/home). Integrate it into your project, by default it logs all the critical crashes but you can add custom logs and access them on fabric dashboard.

Comment: thanks, collect crashes we already have, we also catch react-native error. but warning don't cause a crash, just stop in a view.

Comment: If missing property will cause a crash it will be reported, otherwise if property is missing and it cause a warn that means something is wrong with app logic or your propTypes are not specified correctly.